# App closes after splash screen through Calabash test

Tags: ios-simulator, calabash-ios

When running the "cucumber" command, the iOS Simluator launches and attempts to open my app. The app's splash screen appears and then the simulator goes back to the home screen. I eventually receive an error stating:

```
Time out waiting for UIAutomation run-loop to Start.
```

I can manually start the -cal app in the iOS Simulator through xCode. Any troubleshooting steps I can try to figure out why my app isn't running through the simulator using Calabash?

My environment

```
$xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
$xcodebuild -version
Xcode 6.1.1
Build version 6A2008a
$ calabash-ios version
0.12.2
$ calabash.framework/Resources/version
0.12.2

server_version
{
                         "app_id" => "com.madeupdomain.MyApp-cal",
                        "outcome" => "SUCCESS",
                    "server_port" => 37265,
                        "version" => "0.12.2",
                       "app_name" => "Unknown",
                         "system" => "x86_64",
               "simulator_device" => "iPhone",
                      "simulator" => "",
                    "app_version" => "1.0",
    "iphone_app_emulated_on_ipad" => false,
                            "git" => {
             "revision" => "bafa9fd",
        "remote_origin" => "git@github.com:calabash/calabash-ios-server.git",
               "branch" => "master"
    },
              "screen_dimensions" => {
        "sample" => 1,
        "height" => 1136,
         "width" => 640,
         "scale" => 2
    },
                          "4inch" => true,
                    "iOS_version" => "8.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem several times.

First of all check the **APP_BUNDLE_PATH**
Check the **DEVICE_TARGET** (if your app does not support that target).

Answer (score 0):

Does your app have a Privacy Alert that appears just after launch?

If so, see the advice on this page:

- https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Managing-Privacy-Alerts:--Location-Services,-APNS,-Contacts

Can you update your question with *exact* command you are using to start cucumber?